# Typescript Error, Cannot find name 'gapi', transpile failed

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, google-oauth, typescript2.0

I trying to implement google auth in my ionic2 app. I need it works in browser. So, I installed:

```
npm install --save @types/gapi
npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2
```

There is two warnings:

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0
>   (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for
>   fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

In node_modules folder I have gapi and gapi.auth2 folders but I have typescript error: Cannot find name 'gapi', transpile failed.

I installed

```
npm install typings -g
typings install dt~gapi --global --save
typings install dt~gapi.auth2 --global --save
```

Still have the same error: Cannot find name 'gapi', transpile failed

my code:

```
auth2: any;

login() {
      gapi.load('auth2', () => {
          this.auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
             client_id: 'xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
             scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
          });
        });
      };
```

my package.json:

```
"@angular/core": "2.2.1",
"ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4",
"ionic-native": "2.2.11",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"typescript": "2.0.9"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The current declarations for `gapi`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/60b22cb2397b90138cc61ddab9ec93a15ed99ee7/gapi/index.d.ts) and [for `gapi.auth2`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/60b22cb2397b90138cc61ddab9ec93a15ed99ee7/gapi.auth2/gapi.auth2-tests.ts) are global declarations.

They might not be automatically with `@types` because looking into `node_modules` either requires an explicit `import` or adding your libraries to the `types` field in your `tsconfig.json`.

So try fixing up the following `types` field to your `compilerOptions`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
     "types": ["gapi", "gapi.auth2"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me!
Note that on newer versions of angular-cli, the correct file for these edits might be tsconfig.app.json