# How to use the new @types packages for TypeScript typings?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, definitelytyped

I've started to migrate a large existing, `namespace` and `<reference>` based TypeScript application to use `modules` and the `@types` NPM repository. However, I'm running into problems in every second.

1. Lots of libraries don't even have typings there.
2. Lots of libraries have completely outdated typings there.
3. Lots of libraries have a `global` typings file, resulting that I cannot `import` it because TS complains that it's not a module.
4. When a library has a `module` shaped typing file correctly included in it's NPM package (like `moment.js`), TS still seems to be unable to find it, and errors the line `import * as moment from 'moment'` saying module is not found.

What is the current state of this technique? As I see it at first glance, it seems to be far from being production ready.

What are the hacks and techniques to overcome these issues?

I'm targetting `es5` and using `es6` as `modules` configuration. Can this be the problem? As far as I know TS supports the `es6` module syntax for `es5` output as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current way things are done is definitely production-ready; however, there's a few things which aren't obvious and that isn't your fault.

Let me try to answer your questions one-by-one.

> 1. Lots of libraries don't even have typings there.

In TypeScript 2.1, as long as you have a package installed in `node_modules` and you don't have `noImplicitAny` turned on, you can just import whatever you want.

If you do want to use `noImplicitAny` (which I would recommend for any project that you expect to grow over time), you can just always create a `declarations.d.ts` in your project source folder that declares the modules as you need:

```
// do anything you want when you import `"foo"` now.
declare module "foo";

// can only access the `hello` export when importing `"bar"`.
declare module "bar" {
    export var hello;
}
```

> 2. Lots of libraries have completely outdated typings there.

You should definitely feel free to send a pull request to DefinitelyTyped, but if you're really strapped for time, you can just use the approach I gave for point (1).

> 3. Lots of libraries have a `global` typings file, resulting that I cannot `import` it because TS complains that it's not a module.

If you need to use a global declaration file from DefinitelyTyped, and it's not automatically included in your project, you may have to add it to the `types` field in your `tsconfig.json`.
See my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41416539/typescript-error-cannot-find-name-gapi-transpile-failed/41416926#41416926), but the crux of it is that if you need to include global declarations for the `foo` and `bar` packages, and you have `@types/foo` and `@types/bar` installed, you can write the following in your `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["foo", "bar"]
    }
}
```

> 4. When a library has a `module` shaped typing file correctly included in it's NPM package (like `moment.js`), TS still seems to be unable to find it, and errors the line `import * as moment from 'moment'` saying module is not found.

I believe that this has to do with the fact that you're targetting ES6. Try changing your `"moduleResolution"` option to `"node"` in your `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
}
```

Sorry that that is a gotcha.
The rationale is that the only module loading system that actually has this resolution semantics is CommonJS (the strategy that Node uses).
I agree that that could be improved.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I really appreciate it. I'll take another look at all of my current mess tomorrow and give some feedback.

Comment: Thank you again, I'll accept your answer as it technically answers my questions and gave me some good hints. However, I got stuck with a follow-up question, please see it here if you have a few minutes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474704/how-could-i-update-the-knockout-typing-file-to-be-typescript-2-0-friendly