# How could I update the Knockout typing file to be TypeScript 2.0 friendly?

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I've started to work on modernizing the `knockout` library's TypeScript declaration file which is provided by the `DefinitelyTyped` project.

The declaration file uses some deprecated techniques, and because of this, it's inconvenient to consume it in a TypeScript 2.0+ application.

The current declaration file contains an interface called `KnockoutStatic`. Everything inside this should basically get exported with using the `export declare` `var`/`function` format (if I understand correctly the new declaration file best practices). Then at the end of the file there should be an `export as namespace ko;` statement to be able to consume it as an ambient module.

But rewriting the whole interface to this format is a lot of boring work, so I'm wondering if there exists any trick or syntax to grab this whole interface, and export it's members like they were on the top-level.

I tried several things, for example something like

```
declare var ko: KnockoutStatic;
export default ko;
```

But this of course resulted in having two problems.

1. If I import using `import ko from "knockout"`, then I can use my `ko` object just fine, but I don't have access to the interfaces like `KnockoutObservable<T>`, etc.
2. If I import using `import * as ko from "knockout;` then I have access to interfaces via `ko.KnockoutObservable<T>` which is completely fine, BUT when I want to access the *static*, runtime ko stuff, I end up having another level of `ko` object when consuming, like `ko.ko.observable`, etc.

Another problem is that if I move all the `KnockoutStatic` stuff to the top level, then one can no longer add methods to `ko` for example, as one canot augment a module by adding top-level exports to it (at least this was a TypeScript limitation a few months ago inspired by an ES6 limitation). So from this point of view, the interface solution is better.

I's an important note, that this problem is quite common, as typings of lots of popular libraries suffer from this phenomenon (even ones like `jQuery`). For example `jQuery` has a `JQueryStatic` interface too which should be entirely "lifted" up one level IMO.

Comment: The problem with updating the Knockout type declarations is that there's a long string of globally-written declaration files for things like JQuery and the like that somehow depend on them. I suspect that's why it hasn't been rewritten.

Comment: Actually `knockout` doesn't depend on anything, although you have a good point in general.

Comment: In the meantime I asked a more general technical question about guidance to update existing typing files to match the current recommendations https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13294

Comment: Knockout 3.5 will include a TypeScript declaration file using modern techniques.

Comment: @MichaelBest yeah I know, thanks for pointing this out here. Would you please post it as an answer, so I can close this question?