# Google Sheets API with Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-sheets-api

I want to retrieve formula of cells from spreadsheet using [google sheets api](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/). I did the configurations of credential keys etc. Then I went for javascript setup as mentioned by [google](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js). But got error `cannot find gapi` , so I did this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41416926/2904573) and it worked. But now I am getting error

> Property 'sheets' does not exist on type 'typeof client'.

Have also gone through this [article](http://leifwells.com/2016/06/09/ionic-2--angular-2-using-a-google-spreadsheet-as-a-data-source/) but wasn't much helpful.
Following is my implementation.

**Home.ts**

```
readFromSpreadSheet() {
    gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: 'XXXIDXXX',
      range: 'Sheet1!A1:D7'
    }).then((response) => {
      var result = response.result;
      var numRows = result.values ? result.values.length : 0;
      console.log('${numRows} rows retrieved.');
    });
  }
```

**client_secret.json**

```
{"web":{"client_id":"XXX","project_id":"XXX","auth_uri":"XXX","token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"XXXXX"}}
```

**quickstart.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Sheets API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Google Sheets API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = 'XXXX';
      var API_KEY = 'XXX';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly";

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listMajors();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
       * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
       */
      function listMajors() {
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: 'XXXIDXXX',
          range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
        }).then(function(response) {
          var range = response.result;
          if (range.values.length > 0) {
            appendPre('Name, Major:');
            for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
              var row = range.values[i];
              // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
              appendPre(row[0] + ', ' + row[4]);
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No data found.');
          }
        }, function(response) {
          appendPre('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
        });
      }

    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**No idea what to do with quickstart.html . I have only changed the CLIENT_ID & API_KEY**

**$ ionic info**

> cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
> Cordova Platforms  : none
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> ios-deploy : 1.9.2
> Node       : v8.11.1
> npm        : 6.0.0
> OS         : macOS High Sierra
> Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
> ```
>
> Environment Variables:
>
> ```
> ANDROID_HOME : not set
> ```
>
> Misc:
>
> ```
> backend : pro
> ```

Please suggest steps to integrate google spreadsheet api with ionic or suggest some helpful articles.

Comment: Which ionic version you are using?

Comment: @PareshGami I have added ionic info in my question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

After trying EVERYTHING. I got the answer!

And it is:

**Cordova apps are not supported by gapi.client**

https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/334

**Supported Environments:**

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js#supported-environments

:<

Answer (score 1):

In my project I had used Ionic with React. I followed these steps.

1. in project directory run commands

```
npm install @types/gapi
npm install @types/gapi.client
npm install @types/gapi.client.sheets
npm install @types/gapi.auth2
```

2. In `package.json` use `types` and `typeRoots`

```
{ 
  // ... 
  "types":["gapi"], 
  "typeRoots":["node_modules/@types"], 
  // ...
}
```

3. In `project_directory/src/index.html`

```
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

4. In `.ts` or `tsx` file type, `var gapi=window.gapi;`

this will work fine in ionic localhost development server
for using in android you have to do certain steps more.